# Difficulties in learning physics

Tags: soft-question, education

I have been learning mathematics and now I'm trying to learn physics as well. I have some difficulties:

- (a) There are lots of approximations in physics, and that's very different from mathematics. How should one treat these **approximations**? It seems to me I can only try to **memorize them**, since I haven’t figured out a way to deduce from some 'axioms' which kinds of approximations are necessary/used.
- (b) While in mathematics one can remember the theorems naturally by proving it and understanding it thoroughly, one can't always **prove** statements or formulas in physics so it seems I have to **memorize** them —

  For example, the second thermodynamics law about entropy seems barely provable (at least in the texts I've read I've found no proof), and though I have learnt it for long, honestly I still can't understand it.
- (c) In mathematics, at least in undergrad mathematics, most things are correct (to a large extent, despite that one may find errors in some proof or typos), but in physics, often some parts of the material are incorrect or may be in future proven to be incorrect, (I understand the difficulty of getting things right), or are not stated accurately. These imply if I try to deduce from it something, (as I often do in mathematics), I possibly get something wrong.

  For example, the Newton law says no force implies no change of velocity, but possibly it should be 'in an inertial reference system, no force implies no change of velocity', I remember I once took the former as an accurate expression of Newton's law and thought that statement was true in all reference systems. That confused me and since in an accelerating reference system an object's velocity changes without external forces. Even though that is clearly to me now, similarly things occur to me often in physics.

It's certain that that axiomatic method doesn't always work for physics (or physics as described in many texts), but it does work often and it's a very useful way of thinking (I think) for physics as well, so it seems unwise to completely drop out that way of thinking, so how to deal with this? More exactly how can one know when one can use **axiomatic** method and when one can't?

Comment: You might find Feynman's Messenger Lectures, *The Character of Physical Law*, part 2, [The relation of mathematics and physics](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=zesyeIvbjLQ&list=PLS3_1JNX8dEh5YcO-Y05stU0u_T9nqIlF&index=3&t=0s), to be a useful resource for understanding how both disciplines work and how to move between their different approaches.

Comment: There are different questions here, some of which are on-topic here and some of which probably aren't. The question of how to justify an "approximation" in physics depends very much on the context - many times there is "hard math" underlying the approximation but it's not always the same. Sometimes it's not so much an approximation as a handwavy argument for something that can be shown rigorously, sometimes it really is one. As for "the axiomatic method", there are approaches to physics that rely more on this nd others that rely less on it. You'd have to ask a more specific question about it.

Comment: I see sometimes approximations I see were not originally approximations but replacement of something more complicated.  About axiomatic methods I guess what you mean is some physicists use more mathematical deduction and some use more intuition (and their calculations can be not that strict) and BOTH works. It seems when reading physics one really need to sympathize  with these different approaches, which though can bring some difficulty in understanding. I guess **sympathizing** can bring understanding and is better than just **memorizing**.

Comment: I am a high school student but i would like to share my views is that in physics unless you play with the idea you cant learn it always proving things does not make you learn in physics you have to feel the notion behind law and how it connects to real life that's how i learn it

Comment: That’s very nice lecture.

Comment: Good comment. That resonates with what Feynman said.

Comment: I think part of my confusion is in the language side, I am concerned with how something is stated, or say it’s about in what kind of language physicists describe the world, it seems different physicists (and even the same one at different times) have different styles and what one gets in texts is mixture of all these styles. Often it’s when one understands the stuff and look back and then the mixture of styles is not an issue.

Comment: I guess there is some way to bypass the difficulty caused by the mixture of styles, e.g. explain and deduce things by oneself (and in a consistent way; according to what aspect one tries to understand, either rigorous/formal language like or intuitive/daily language like), that way the language becomes one’s own, i.e. consistent. —part of that is Feynman’s way.

Comment: @CharlieChang, I have a chemical engineering background, so I'll give you a different perspective.  Given a physical phenomenon that I want to model, among all the possible models that I may choose to employ, I want to use the simplest mathematical model that gives me the accuracy that I desire.  Note that NONE of the possible models gives me an exact representation, but I am more interested in practicality than mathematical exactness.

Comment: That works sometimes! But pardon me for guessing that possibly in physics complicated mathematics is used for a reason, even though no model is exact; perhaps it’s because physics wanna find some law that’s useful for many cases, and the more accurate the model, the more widely it can be applied, (since an approximation causing no issue in a case may cause issues in another) so the cost of finding as accurate mathematical descriptions can pay off. I think either approach is okay, depending on the purpose.

Comment: I guess an important point, as Feynman said, is in physics, beside summarizing results into mathematics, one needs to translate maths into ‘English’ (interpretations about the real world) and if one keeps that **translation view (understanding that translation makes things more comprehensible but always causes loss of some meanings)** in mind he is fine.